# "He works/worked hard so that he will be promoted."

Tags: backshifting

my sentence:
**(1)** *He **works** hard **so that** he will be promoted*.
Am I right that (1) has two meanings?:
**(1a)** *He **works** hard **in order that** he will be promoted*.
**(1b)** *He **works** hard **with the result that** he will be promoted*.

I backshift (1) but don't replace "will" with "would" to emphasize he hasn't been promoted yet:
**(2)** *He **worked** hard **so that** he will be promoted*.
Am I right that (2) has two meanings?:
**(2a)** *He **worked** hard **in order that** he will be promoted*.
**(2b)** *He **worked** hard **with the result that** he will be promoted*.

Answer (score 8):

Example #1 means 1a. To get sense 1b, remove the word ***that*** from #1.

Example #2 is a potentially awkward mix of tenses, but it's essentially the same thing
Example #2 means 2a, and #2 without ***that*** means 2b

In short, ***so that*** means ***in order that, with the intent that***, but plain ***so*** means ***therefore, hence.***

Comment: [cambridge.org](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/so-that-or-in-order-that) writes: "_So that_" can also mean "_with the result that_": "_The birds return every year around March, so that April is a good time to see them_." — You write: "_so that_" means "_in order that_", but plain "_so_" means "_therefore_".  — Can I infer from your answer and Cambridge: "_so that_" means "_with the result that_" only if "_so that_" is used in that sentence where it can't mean "_in order that_"?

Comment: What you can infer is I don't think much of that final example from cambridge. Maybe 1 in 10 (perhaps 1 in 100 or 1 in 1000) native Anglophones would include ***that*** in the "birds" example. Ignore it. The extraneous "that" *may* have been more likely a few centures ago, but I wouldn't like to say even that.

Comment: [britannica.com](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/so): "_Please be quiet so I can study_." Here "so" = "in order that".  Since you said only "so that" can mean "in order that", I infer this example is unnatural to you, right? Thanks.

Comment: No, I have no problem with discarding ***that*** in contexts like *Please turn around so I can get dressed*, where it can't affect the meaning whether it's present or not. I just meant I don't like the "birds" example because *superficially* it seems to be suggesting that the birds might come in March *in order to* make April a good time for "twitchers". But bear in mind I'm a native speaker, so I automatically know when I can get away with things like that. You as a non-native speaker would probably be safer sticking with *Please be quiet so **that** I can study*.

Comment: ...I think realistically it's simply not practical for nns to attempt to learn subtle aspects of English usages like this from reference books or Q&A sites. The "default" usages are as outlined above, and you should only really start to ignore the defaults when you've read and heard enough English to *know* that whatever "departure from the norm" you contemplate often occurs among the natives anyway.

Comment: I agree with @FumbleFingers both in their answer and that the Cambridge definition and birds example sound wrong. It's possible "so that" has been used that way and Cambridge includes it for the sake of completeness, but to my Canadian ears, it's wrong.

Comment: @gotube: In all fairness though, the cambridge item is a final point in the *Grammar > Easily confused words > **So that or in order that?*** page - almost an *afterthought* - where it says *So that (but not in order that) **can also mean** ‘with the result that’:* I'd say it's only there for completeness (undeniably the usage *does* occur); it's not really for teaching nns how to speak English! And although I think their example usage is badly-chosen, there will be formal contexts in scientific papers, say, where it's far less "suspect".

Comment: To get the "therefore" sense you also should have a comma before "so".